# I want to convert ArrayList data of Accelometer into text file and store to Android phone

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener,
     View.OnClickListener {
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Button btnStart, btnStop, btnView,btnActivity;
private boolean started = false;
private ArrayList<String> sensorData = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to convert this `sensorData` ArrayList into text file and to store in Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

Some APIs are available to store data in Android devices directly from the JAVA code of one application.

As an example, you can use DOM and/or SAX to store your ArrayList in an XML document. 
These are official APIs and you can find it here : https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html